# Return the first element of a list inside an object using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream, option-type

I'm unsure how to do this,

I have an object named `StudentCollection` which contains a list field `students`.

```
public class StudentCollection {
     private List<Student> students;
     //getter and setter
}
```

Is there any way to get the first element of the students list ( `Student` object), by checking that `StudentCollection` and `students` are not null using **Java 8 (Optional/Stream)**.

I knew this is a simple task with pre java8 code.!

Comment: show what u've done so far student

Comment: You don't need Optional, nor Stream to do that. Just two null checks and a call to List.get(). The List should never be null. Make that an invariant of your class, and everything will be simpler.

Comment: I really don't see why you cannot just do null checks and then do `students.get(0)`. Java 8 features aren't a magical tool that can and should be used for everything. I've seen so many questions along the lines of "I know how to do this, but is there a way to do it in java 8 and preferably only one command?" that it really boggles my mind.

Comment: The best option is to never allow these objects to be `null` in the first place. That’s especially true for the `List`. If there are no students, the list should be empty rather than `null`. Besides that, does this `StudentCollection` serve any purpose besides being a superfluous wrapper around a `List<Student>`?

Comment: The question is so simple. How can we do it in Java8.! JB Nizet @Oh God Spiders I don’t need your the help to do the null check. Federico and Lino Thanks for the answer..

Comment: @Newbie null checks are possible in Java 8 too. And they are the best solution to your problem. Just because cars exist doesn't mean that they're the best way to go from your kitchen to your bath room. Your legs continue to be the best way to do that, even if cars are newer than legs.

Comment: @JBNizet It's also good to know how the cars perform in the long run. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following by using `Optional` and `Streams`.

```
StudentCollection sc = ...;
final Optional<Student> student = Optional.ofNullable(sc)
    .map(StudentCollection::getStudents)
    .map(Collection::stream) 
    .flatMap(Stream::findFirst);
```

The optional is used to safely handle the `StudentCollection` or the `List<Student>` which might by null.

---

As mentioned in the comment by @GhostCat the overhead created by above snippet is *horribly* big. Because you're using quite expensive API-methods for such a simple task.

As @Holger suggested, you can reduce the overhead by not using the `Stream`-API:

```
StudentCollection sc = ...;
final Optional<Student> student = Optional.ofNullable(sc)
    .map(StudentCollection::getStudents)
    .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()) 
    .map(list -> list.get(0));
```

Which still yields the same result as the prior snippet.

---

When you don't want any overhead you can use the following "old" (pre `Java8`) way:

```
StudentCollection sc = ...;
Student student = null;
if(sc != null){
    List<Student> students = sc.getStudents();
    if(students != null && !students.isEmpty()){
        student = students.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The usual thing: it looks cool and swift, but the *overhead* behind is probably enormous. I agree with the comments given to the question itself - streams/optionals aren't the answer to everything. Two simple checks and a get(0) is all you need and *want* here.

Comment: perhaps, instead of `.map(Collection::stream)  .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)` you could use `.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()) .map(l -> l.get(0))`; that doesn’t use neat method references, but also doesn’t need additional resources.

Comment: @GhostCat yes that's true. But I am assuming the OP knows the normal way. But just wants to see how it's done in java 8

Comment: @Holger that indeed does work too i'll edit that into my answer

Answer (score 1):

The best code is the one which best expresses the intention of the developer. With this in mind, I would simply go for:

```
return yourStudentCollection != null && 
       yourStudentCollection.getStudents() != null &&
      !yourStudentCollection.getStudents().isEmpty()  ?
           yourStudentCollection.getStudents().get(0) :
           null;
```

This is a good fit for `Optional`, though. I would return an `Optional<Student>`:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(yourStudentCollection)
       .map(sc -> sc.getStudents())
       .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
       .map(s -> s.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
class Student{
    String s;

    public Student(String s) {this.s = s;}
    public String getString() {return s;}
}

class StudentCollection {
    private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public StudentCollection(List<Student> studentList) {this.studentList = studentList;}
    public List<Student> getStudentList() {return studentList;}
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList.add(new Student("First Student"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Second Student"));

        StudentCollection studentCollection = new StudentCollection(studentList);
        String s = studentCollection.getStudentList().stream().findFirst().orElse(new Student("None")).getString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The result will be the first student.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?
Is there everything alright?

Answer (score -3):

list is private you can't directly access it but create a get method :

```
public Student getFirstStudent() {
   if (!this.students.isEmpty()) {
       return this.students.get(0);
   }
}
```

and in your other class :

```
StudentCollection SC =  new StudentCollection();
Student stu = SC.getFirstStudent();
```

Comment: `if (this.students)` will not compile unless `this.students` is a boolean.

Comment: That is not what he is asking for. Not at all.

Comment: `array` is not a `list`. Either use `array.length` and `array[0]` or `list.size()` and `list.get(0)`

Comment: @LeoR. there is no need to be rude. `this.students.size` will not compile, because `size()` is a method and not a property, like `length`. Also instead of checking if `students.size() > 0` you might want to use `!students.isEmpty()`